# くださるんじゃ...: Formal, semi-casual, poor usage, etc.?

Tags: keigo

> それって先生が決めて、一緒に行ってくださるんじゃ…。

*From [Japanesetest4you](http://japanesetest4you.com/japanese-language-proficiency-test-jlpt-n3-listening-exercise-6/).

**My understanding:**

1. **くださる** is the honorific version of **くれる**
2. **ん** is from **の**, **explanatory**
3. **じゃ**, contracted **では**, usually in the form of **rhetorical じゃない**, or the slangy **じゃん**

**My problem here:**

1. Is **ない** left out of the sentence? I think I've only seen **じゃない/じゃん** so far.
2. **くださる** is **尊敬語** unless I had been hopelessly mistaken for months. However, this **くださるんじゃ** somehow looks, and sounds really casual to me. Is the speaker sneaking in a hint of **砕けた言い方** in the guise of **敬語**? I also feel that by speaking this way, the speaker is hiding a sense of affected ignorance of responsibility, but I may be reading too much into this.

教えていただけませんか。お願いいたします！

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. 「ないんですか？」 or something similar is left out after 「～んじゃ...」

The full sentence would be like:

> それって先生が決めて、一緒に行ってくださるんじゃ**ないんですか？**

but it's quite common to cut off sentences like this in daily conversation. 
And I think you'd usually sound a bit less decisive/interrogatory and therefore a bit more humble and softer when speaking this way.

Example:

「これって、間違ってるんじゃ**ないですか**？」→「これって、間違ってるんじゃ・・・」

---

2. You're right that 「くださるんじゃ…」 is a bit more casual than 「くださるのでは…」.
   「くださるのでは（ないのですか？ / ありませんか？）」 would sound more formal.

Comment: huh...  @Chocolate, so, Japanese natives always hear an unspoken negative question when this grammar point comes up? It's never construed as a suggestion, or an "if/then" sort of thing?

Comment: ^ never ってことはないと思いますが…。文脈によるのでは…(ないでしょうか)。